# setShowModal does not work Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to show a modal dialog once the countdown timer has finished. I call the state function in a condition where if seconds === 0 but i keep getting this error "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." Which part that I did wrong?

```html
let [showModal, setShowModalDialog] = useState(false)
let countRef1 = useRef()
useEffect(() => { getPushNoti() }, [])

const getPushNoti = async () => {
        let sendNoti = 1

         <some code implementation>
         
        if (sendNoti === 1) {
            countRef1.current = setInterval(() => {
                if (secondsPush > 0) {
                    setSecondsPush((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1)
                }

            }, 1000)
        }
    }

if (secondsPush === 0) {
        clearInterval(countRef1.current)
        setShowModalDialog(true)
    }
    
    {showModal ? (
             <Modal> is here           
 ) : null}
```

Comment: can you update the code section to more detailed one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check this condition `(secondsPush === 0)` inside a `useEffect` hook and add `secondsPush` as a dependency for the `hook` so that the `useEffect` hook will run everytime the value of `secondsPush` changes:

```
let [showModal, setShowModalDialog] = useState(false)
let countRef1 = useRef()
useEffect(() => { getPushNoti() }, [])

const getPushNoti = async () => {
    let sendNoti = 1

     <some code implementation>
     
    if (sendNoti === 1) {
        countRef1.current = setInterval(() => {
            if (secondsPush > 0) {
                setSecondsPush((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1)
            }

        }, 1000)
    }
}


useEffect(() => { 
  if (secondsPush === 0) {
    clearInterval(countRef1.current)
    setShowModalDialog(true)
  }
}, [secondsPush])

{showModal ? (
         <Modal> is here           
) : null}
```

Comment: yes it worked, thanks! But why do we need 2 useEffect() instead of 1?

Comment: Each of the `useEffect` has its own responsibility. You should use `useEffect` hook when you want to run an operation based on a state change.